# Should I notice a difference in using Task vs Threads in .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task

I updated my code to use Tasks instead of threads....

Looking at memory usage and CPU I do not notices any improvements on the multi-core PC, Is this expected?

My application essentially starts up threads/tasks in different objects when it runs...

All I'm doing is a simple

```
Task a = new Task(...)
a.Start();
```

Comment: "I do not notices any improvements" That would depend soo much on the actual code...  You could even have seen a deterioration.

Comment: `Tasks` aren't magic classes. In the end they are `threads` too,

Comment: I just though Tasks are cognisant of the multi-core environment unlike threads, so would know how to distriubute themselves properly on multi-cores. Also since they do not need to be created since they use the ThreadPool they would be more memory effcient.

Comment: @Allen Ho, regarding performance benefits from pooling, this will likely only be noticeable if you used to start up new Threads very frequently and they perform short-running tasks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are various implications to using Tasks instead of Threads, but performance isn't a major one (assuming you weren't creating huge numbers of threads.)  A few key differences:

1. The default TaskScheduler will use thread pooling, so some Tasks may not start until other pending Tasks have completed.  If you use Thread directly, every use will start a new Thread.
2. When an exception occurs in a Task, it gets wrapped into an AggregateException that calling code can receive when it waits for the Task to complete or if you register a continuation on the Task.  This is because you can also do things like wait on multiple Tasks to complete, in which case multiple exceptions can be thrown and aggregated.
3. If you don't observe an unhandled exception thrown by a Task, it will (well, may) eventually be thrown *by the finalizer of the Task*, which is particularly nasty.  I always recommend hooking the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event so that you can at least log these failures before the application blows up.  This is different from Thread exceptions, which show up in the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice overview. I'm researching the first point now, it sounds interesting to use a TaskScheduler.

Comment: @Kosko, one common use of TaskScheduler is [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx), which schedules tasks to a synchronization context (typically the UI thread.)  This is most commonly used when registering continuations on a Task, so that the continuation runs in the UI thread rather than on the thread pool.  It can help avoid a lot of ugly Invoke code in your UI update methods.

Answer (score 8):

If you simply replaced every usage of `Thread` with `Task` and did no other changes I would expect virtually the same performance.  The `Task` API is really just that, it's an API over an existing set of constructs.  Under the hood it uses threads to schedule it's activities and hence has similar performance characteristics.

What's great about `Task` are the new things you can do with them

- Composition with `ContinueWith`
- Cancellation
- Hierarchies
- Etc ...

Comment: TPL gets rid of code obfuscating bloat. It is the API that every developer ends up wanting to write but doesn't have to the time to do so.

Answer (score 4):

One great improvement of Takss vs. Threads is that you can easiely build chains of tasks. You can specify when a task should start after the previous task ("OnSuccess", "OnError", a.s.o.) and you can specify if there should be a synchronization context switch. That gives you the great opportunity to run a long running task in bakcground and after that a UI refershing task on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.0 then you can use the Parallel.Invoke method like so

```
Parallel.Invoke(()=> {
    // What ever code you add here will get threaded.
});
```

for more info see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx

Comment: So What? Have you read the question? `Looking at memory usage and CPU I do not notices any improvements on the multi-core PC, Is this expected?`

Comment: it is my understanding that Parallel.Invoke has better multicore usage.  Now I could be wrong about that and if so please educate me.

Comment: 1) Maybe, `Parallel.Invoke` is implemented with `Tasks`? 2) Where is the answer for `Is this expected?`

Comment: I belive so...  The Tasks Api was created before multicore was an industry standard and to my understanding never was refactored to handle multicore effeciantly.  This is essentially why they came out with the Parallel Api.  This is speculation, but perhaps they did not want to change the Task api beacuse its used in production in several applications.  So they made a brand new one and gave developers the options. Sorry I did not explain it out. Thought the answer was in context.

Answer (score 0):

You would see difference if your original or converted code **do not** utlize CPU completely. I.e. if original code always limited number of threads to 2, on quad-core machine it will run at about 50% load with manually created threads and potentially 100% load with tasks (if your tasks can be actaully paralellized). So it looks like either your original code was reasonable from performance point of view, or both implemetaion suffer issues showing similar underutiliztion of CPU.